# Display last several records of sql in html divs

Tags: html, mysql

I want to display the last 3 rows of mysql table, each row should appear in a separate div. I was able to display the last row but couldn't figure out how to display the other two that are before it. here's how I did it:

```
<?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id_movie=(select max(id_movie) from movies)";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("erreurrequete");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                printf("<div class='col-md-4 text-center'>
                    <img class='img-thumbnail' src='%s'>
                    <h3>%s</h3>
                    <h3>%s</h3>
                    </div>", $row['img_movie'], $row['title'], $row['boxoffice']);
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query : `SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY id_movie DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! sorry I can't give +1 cos I'm still new